# Diagonal Matrix of Sigma Values in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

If I compute the SVD of a matrix A in Julia, it will give the sigma values of the matrix, BUT NOT in matrix form. However, if I want to ***assemble the sigma values of a matrix A into a diagonal matrix***, is there any way to do this other than manually typing out the sigma values into the Diagonal() function?

Comment: Have you tried `Diagonal(svd(A).S)`?